# Hiding/Showing portions of HTML page based on user input

Tags: javascript, html

I have a web page that lists open jobs at a company, in the following format:

Title: JavaScript Developer

State: Maryland

Description: a;dlksfja;slfdja;sklfja;sldkfjas a;sldkfj a;lskdf a;slkdfj a;lsdkfj a;sdfj a;lsdkfj a;lsdkfj a;lsdkfj ;alsdkfj a;lskdjf ;alskdjf a;lsdkfj a;lsdkfj a;lsdkfj a;lsdkfj a;slkdfj a;lskdfj a;lsdkfj a;lsdkjf ;alskdjf ;alskdjf ;alsdkjf ;alsdkfj a;lskdjf a;lskdj f;alsdkfj a;lsdkfj as;dlfkj a;slkdfj ;alsdkjf ;asld jf;alskdjf ;alsdkjf a;sdlfjk asd jf;asdkjlf ;asdklf j;as dfla;skdj f;alskdjf a;sld fa;sldkfj a;lsdkfj a;sldfj

Salary Range: $75,000 - $80,000

Categories: Software Development, UI/UX

---

Title: Network Security Analyst

State: Illinois

Description: a;dlksfja;slfdja;sklfja;sldkfjas a;sldkfj a;lskdf a;slkdfj a;lsdkfj a;sdfj a;lsdkfj a;lsdkfj a;lsdkfj ;alsdkfj a;lskdjf ;alskdjf a;lsdkfj a;lsdkfj a;lsdkfj a;lsdkfj a;slkdfj a;lskdfj a;lsdkfj a;lsdkjf ;alskdjf ;alskdjf ;alsdkjf ;alsdkfj a;lskdjf a;lskdj f;alsdkfj a;lsdkfj as;dlfkj a;slkdfj ;alsdkjf ;asld jf;alskdjf ;alsdkjf a;sdlfjk asd jf;asdkjlf ;asdklf j;as dfla;skdj f;alskdjf a;sld fa;sldkfj a;lsdkfj a;sldfj

Salary Range: $85,000 - $90,000

Categories: Cyber, Networking

---

Title: Cyber Software Engineer - Hadoop

State: Maryland

Description: a;dlksfja;slfdja;sklfja;sldkfjas a;sldkfj a;lskdf a;slkdfj a;lsdkfj a;sdfj a;lsdkfj a;lsdkfj a;lsdkfj ;alsdkfj a;lskdjf ;alskdjf a;lsdkfj a;lsdkfj a;lsdkfj a;lsdkfj a;slkdfj a;lskdfj a;lsdkfj a;lsdkjf ;alskdjf ;alskdjf ;alsdkjf ;alsdkfj a;lskdjf a;lskdj f;alsdkfj a;lsdkfj as;dlfkj a;slkdfj ;alsdkjf ;asld jf;alskdjf ;alsdkjf a;sdlfjk asd jf;asdkjlf ;asdklf j;as dfla;skdj f;alskdjf a;sld fa;sldkfj a;lsdkfj a;sldfj

Salary Range: $120,000 - $130,000

Categories: Software Engineering, Cyber, BigData

etc.

When I only had a few jobs to list, the above style was fine.  Now I have nearly 100, and I need to give the user a way to filter which jobs they see.  I'd like to filter by both "State" and by various "Types".  See above for some examples and note that each job can have only one State, but it may have 1 or more Types.

I'd like to add a simple filtering section at the top of the page, where the user can do the following:

1) Select from a "State" drop down that lists each US state, plus an "All" option.

2) Select from a "Type" drop down that lists each Type we use to classify jobs, plus an "All" option.

3) Click on a "Filter" button that makes the matching jobs visible and hides the ones that don't match.

I do NOT need multi-select capabilities within the State or Type fields.

Any suggestions on how to do this in the most simple fashion would be highly appreciated.  There isn't any database involved in the website - it is just a static site and I update this page once a week as new jobs open and close.  Simple manual updates are completely fine once I have this working.

Thank you.

Comment: jQuery could make short work of this. Are you opposed to using it at all?

Comment: I'm not opposed to jQuery - I just don't know it and need to get this done with only a few hours of work, so I'm looking for the simplest means possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you'll need JavaScript for that (it's not possible with pure HTML)

Define your filterable content in divs with ids then use something like

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   var sel = document.getElementById('yourDropDown');
   sel.onchange = function() {
      var show = document.getElementById('yourDivId');
      show.style.display='none';
   }
   </script>
```

cheers